# What to get values in database using query

Tags: sql-server

I want to get values from a SQL Server database:

First table contains these values

```
no name
1 John
2 smith
```

Second table contains these values:

```
no name
 1 John
 2 smith
 3 miller
 4 pointing
```

I don't want the values which are same and I need the remind names by using inner join I want

The query I used:

```
select * 
from table1 
where name In (select * from table2)
```

Comment: Please add expected output.

Comment: i am getting the out put as john,smith. i want remaining values. which was in table2.

Comment: In table1 i am selecting john and in table2 the same name john is there . i want the name from table1(John)and the remaining names from table2.

Comment: @VinothKannan have you tried right join ? and again please post your required resultset.

Answer (score 0):

```
select no, name
from   table1 

UNION ALL

select no, name
from   table2 t2
where  no NOT IN (select no, name
                  from   table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select no, name from table2
except
select no, name from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* 
from table1 a left join table2 b on a.name=b.name
where b.id is null
```